# I am writing a regex to handle the following but i am stuck in between

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

Requirements:

- There can be no capital letters in the string.
- The string cannot contain any of the characters '^$.?*+()'
- If '[' is present in the string it must be followed by zero or more characters other than '[' and ']', which must be followed by ']'. For example, [test] is valid, whereas [test not valid, test] and [[test]] are not valid. [test][test] is valid.
- '|' can be used if there is words after | like ||| not valid but |test valid word| not valid

```
function charPos(str, char) {
     return str
         .split("")
         .map(function (c, i) { if (c == char) return i; })
         .filter(function (v) { return v >= 0; });
   }

function testString(urlPattern)
{



let regex = /[ $^*()+\[\]\\|.\/?]/g;


if(regex.test(urlPattern)){
      let secondRegex =  true;
      let thirdRegex =  true;
      let regexData = /[ $^*()+\\\\.\/?]/g;
      let regexDataNew = /[ $^*()+\\\.\/?]/g;
      if(urlPattern.indexOf("[") < urlPattern.indexOf("]") && !regexData.test(urlPattern)){
        secondRegex =  false;
      }
      if(urlPattern.indexOf("[") == -1 && urlPattern.indexOf("]") == -1){
        secondRegex =  false;
      }
      if(urlPattern.indexOf("[[") != -1 || urlPattern.indexOf("]]") != -1){
        secondRegex =  true;
      }
      let pos = charPos(urlPattern,'|');
      let largest = pos.sort((a,b)=>a-b)[pos.length - 1];
      if(largest+1 < urlPattern.length && !regexDataNew.test(urlPattern)){
        thirdRegex =  false;
      }
      if(urlPattern.indexOf("|") == -1 ){
        thirdRegex =  false;
      }
      if(secondRegex || thirdRegex){
        return 'Not Valid';
      }
      else {
        return 'Valid';
      }
     
    }
    else {
        return 'Valid1';
    }

 }
    // test case

   testString('testttthhh@@|sss'); working
   testString('testttthhh@@|'); working
   testString('testttthhh@@|[]')  working but need to show invalid.
```

If anyone have some solution or face same type problem help me to sort it out.

Thanks

Comment: Checkout **[Regex101](https://regex101.com/)**.  It includes string testing and a super helpful quick reference guide for several flavors, including ECMAScript (JavaScript).

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make the requirements more clear. You will see that the third and fourth points are still not clear, however. That's because I don't understand precisely what is permitted and not permitted there. You need to edit your question to make the points correct and unambious. You also need to change the title, which, I hate to say, is awful. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use match any char except the chars that you don't want to match.

If you reach either a pipe or an opening square bracket, you assert either that that pipe is followed for example a word character like a-z, digits or an underscore.

In case you encounter an opening square bracket, you match it until a closing one, and assert that there is not another one following.

If an empty string should not be matched, you can start the pattern with a negative lookahead `^(?!$)`

```
^[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]*(?:(?:\[[^\s\[\]\\]+](?!\])|\|[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]+)[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]*)*$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]*` Match 0+ times any char except the listed
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\[[^\s\[\]\\]+](?!\])` Match from `[`...`]` not followed by `]`
    - `|` Or
    - `\|[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]+` Match a pipe and match 1+ times any listed word chars
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]*` Match 0+ times any char except the listed
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times as there does not have to be a `|` or `[]` present
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jTxDxA/1)

```js
let pattern = /^[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]*(?:(?:\[[^\s\[\]\\]+](?!\])|\|[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]+)[^\s\[\]^$.|?*+()A-Z\\]*)*$/;
[
  "testttthhh@@|sss",
  "[]",
  "test test",
  "test\\test",
  "word|@pro",
  "word|%pro%",
  "testttthhh@@|",
  "testttthhh@@|[]",
  "[test]",
  "[test",
  "test]",
  "[[test]]",
  "[test][test]",
  "|||",
  "|test",
  "word|",
  "Atest"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(pattern.test(s) + " --> " + s);
});
```

Comment: We have a ways to go to work out the details of what is being asked, so more edits may be in the offing.

Comment: I noticed my regex is shorter than yours (78 vs 79 character).

Comment: If this were [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) someone would probably have found a killer regex with 27 characters.

Comment: A small thing I noticed awhile back: while it's often prudent to include `\r?` in `[xyz\r?\n]`, I don't know if it ever need be added to `[^abc\n]`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird  Sir 2 case is miss, no space is allowed in between the string.
and if [] mean [ empty] than not allowed.

Comment: @FullStackDev I have updated the answer. Now there is no space allowed, and empty `[]` is also not allowed.

Comment: @Thefourthbird one more thing need to add. need to validate the \ to if this is in string than it will show false

Comment: @FullStackDev I have updated the answer. It does not match \ now

Comment: @Thefourthbird Works great very very thanks you :) but it not allow the other special charcter other than  '^$.?*+()' as it need to allow the other special charcter after |
Like word|@pro , word|%pro% %word%|%pro% etc

Comment: @FullStackDev I see, updated it so now you can match any char except the not allowed after the `|`

Comment: @Thefourthbird can you do me a one favour for this.

I like to exlude this too. %, 
 %%, %word, word%

Comment: @Thefourthbird That example dont allow. %sssss% i like to allow this .

Comment: You can use an alternation to allow that https://regex101.com/r/LYHOGO/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird not working for this "%word%|%word%"

Comment: There can be a lot of edge cases here https://regex101.com/r/TQItNK/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217906/discussion-between-fullstack-dev-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: @Thefourthbird %sss%ddd|% this need to show error but it is not showing this is the last case

Comment: Can you be more specific about the matches and update the link with what should and should not match?

Answer (score 2):

You can test the string with the following regular expression.

```
/^(?!.*\|\S*\|)(?!.*[$^.?*+()A-Z])[^\[\]\n]*(?:\[[^\[\]\n]*\][^\[\]\n]*)*[^\[\]\n]*$/
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/5ADOQs/2/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                : match beginning of string
(?!              : begin negative lookahead
  .*\|\S*\|      : match 0+ chars followed by '|' follow by 0+
                   non-whitespace chars followed by |'
)                : end negative lookahead
(?!              : begin negative lookahead
  .*             : match 0+ chars
  [$^.?*+()A-Z]  : match a char in the char class
)                : end negative lookahead
[^\[\]\n]*       : match 0+ chars other than those char class
(?:              : begin a non-capture group
  \[             : match '['
  [^\[\]\n]*     : match 0+ chars other than those in char class
  \]             : match ']'
  [^\[\]\n]*     : match 0+ chars other than those in char class
)                : end non-capture group
*                : execute non-capture group 0+ times
[^\[\]\n]*       : match 0+ chars other than those char class
$                : match end of string
```

Comment: Sir 2 case is miss, no space is allowed in between the string.
and if [] mean [ empty] than not allowed.